# Benchmarking sorting algorithms on collection of integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, iterator

I'm working on a very basic benchmark of some popular sorting algorithms on a set of arrays. I wanted to store them in a List (Maybe a bad idea) and return the time it takes to sort the arrays using the nanosecond difference. I am almost there but I understand I'm returning the cumulative total time at each iteration of the iterator rather than only the total time at the end. I do get the total time at the end but I'm a bit stumped how to get only the total time output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    makeArray(100, 50);  //make 100 arrays at size 50
    System.out.println();
        BubbleSort bs = new BubbleSort();    //Create bs obj
    for (Iterator<int[]> iterator = listOfArrays.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        int[] isSort = (int[]) iterator.next();
        double time =(bs.benchmark(isSort));  //pass iterators arrays to benchmark method
        System.out.println("Total time: " + time);
    }//rof
}//main
```

In my runner class main method I make a number of arrays, add them to a Static ArrayList (also a bad idea probably) and pass those via an iterator to my benchmarking method below which in turn sorts the array.

```
public double benchmark(int[] toSort){
    double startTime = System.nanoTime();
    bubble(toSort);
    double endTime = System.nanoTime();
    double timeElapsed = endTime - startTime ;
    double elapsedMillis = timeElapsed/1000000;
    total+=elapsedMillis;  //total is a static class variable but this isnt viable longterm imo
    return total;  //this is returned after each array in the collection is sorted obviously
}//benchmark
```

I understand its a bit messy, its just a rough first draft but I'm just in need of a little kick in the right direction.

Comment: So your goal is to only print out the total time at the very end? Since it seems that `total` is an attribute in your Benchmark class, you could just return that after you ran through all of your entries.

Comment: I had thought about making a getTotal method and returning the static total double with a separate method call after calling the benchmark, changing the benchmarking method to a void type but I feel like its already so inefficient I'd probably be making it worse. Maybe not